# What is the difference between "трогать" and "касаться"?

Tags: разница

What is the difference between **трогать** (to touch) and **касаться**? Are they just synonyms or I should use each word in  a specific case?

Comment: Meaning "touch " they are synonymous, but each has more than one meaning.

Comment: in physical sense **трогать** belongs to lower register and sounds grosser, it also can have sexual connotations, **касаться** is closer to **дотрагиваться** not less by the virtue of belonging to the same group of verbs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Трогать` usually is more intense. You can think of `касаться` of a single, atomic action, it's to touch once and/or to touch subtly, while `трогать` is to touch thoroughly and/or to touch many times. That's why `касаться` has second, figurative meaning "to mention something, to cover some issue but not necessarily in detail", like in phrase: "Что до вопросов экономических, их президент только коснулся".

Also if the action has a connotation of unintentional action, `коснуться` is most likely to be used.

Also, there are cases when these verbs are not synonymous at all and can not be interchanged by any means. `Меня это не трогает`is - it doesn't bother me", `меня это не касается` - it's none of my concern.

Comment: to add, in figurative use a synonym of **касаться** is **затрагивать**, а cognate of **трогать**

Comment: One more thing to add: `касаться` can be unintentional (e.g. when you are in confined space), while `трогать` is always intentional

Comment: Трогать - умышленно, имеет негативную коннотацию "трогал ли он тебя в детстве?". Больше относится к одушевлённым предметам. Есть переносный смысл "не трогай его!" - подразумевает не только физическое прикосновение, но вообще контакт, синонимы в данном случае: отстань, не связывайся.

Comment: @user7568519 я не совсем согласен, потому что фраза "прикасался ли он тебя в детстве" тоже, знаете, так себе звучит. Но да, хорошее замечание про трогать = беспокоить.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to think about it is "трогать" is "to touch" or "to be touching", which implies a more deliberate action, while "касаться" is more like "to be in contact with", which can be unintentional, or passive in the case of inanimate objects.

You can say "стол касается стены," "the table is in contact with the wall", but you can't say "стол трогает стену," that almost sounds like "the table is grabbing/groping the wall" or something that is active and requires hands.

Comment: at the same time it's not incorrect to say **стол дотрагивается до стены**

Comment: Yep, although usually a bit weird. Касается and договаривается are similar in meaning. Both касаться and договариваться are passive states, while трогать is a active action.

Comment: договаривается -> you meant **дотрагивается**

Comment: Oops, yeah. Autocorrect fail

Answer (score 0):

**Трогать** - умышленно, иногда имеет негативную коннотацию "трогал ли он тебя?".

Больше относится к одушевлённым существам. Пример: *можно потрогать (т.е. погладить) собаку?*

Есть переносный смысл "*не трогай его!*" - подразумевает не только физическое прикосновение, но вообще контакт, синонимы в данном случае: *отстань, не связывайся*.

Пример: *потрогал лоб* (проверил отсутствие температуры/жара/лихорадки).

Переносный смыл: "(за-)тронуть душу" - см. *трогательный*. Относится к психике (эмоциям).

Касаться - неумышленно, непроизвольно, неодушевлённых предметов (волосы касаются подушки, одежда коснулась тела).

**Трогать** - более **продолжительно** по времени (с дополнительными ощущениями - потрогать и **почувствовать тепло/форму/структуру**), **потрогать** похоже на **пощупать**/ощупать.

**Коснуться/прикоснуться** - это нажать/провести.

Пример: *коснулся экрана* [смартфона/планшета]

Переносный смысл:
1) касаться темы (в разговоре)
2) это меня не касается (не моё дело)